# sleep in Bash if/else sleep vs <condition> && sleep clamining cpu

Tags: bash, cpu, sleep, resources

I wrote a script to check on the battery and if it is below 5% notify the user.

The script is put to sleep for 1 minute after every check.

If I write the script in the following way, the cpu workload will rise to great extend:

```
#!/bin/sh

while true; do
  [[
    $(
      upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0 |
      grep percentage |
      grep -Poe  "\d*"
    ) -lt 5
  ]] &&
  notify-send "Battery below 5%" &&
  sleep 60
done
```

Do you know why the cpu went up?
[image: the notify command and the upower command dont free cpu resources]

You can see in the image, that a lot of cpu resources are claimed. They will not be cleared.

If I write the script in a more conventional way, with simple if/else blocks, everything works as expected and the cpu will only go up for a short time in the beginning and after the sleep period is over:

```
while true; do
  if [[ 
      $(
        upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0 |
        grep percentage |
        grep -Poe  "\d*"
      ) -lt 5
     ]]; then
    notify-send "Battery below 5%"
  else
    sleep 60
  fi
done
```

Do you know why this behaviour is happening?

Comment: When you invoke `notify-send "Battery below 5%" && echo Success` does the output include the word "Success"?

Comment: `sleep 60` is never triggering in the false case, as you combine all actions with `&&` so it runs in an endless loop.

Comment: At some point, you will have this script running in the background, and you will want to terminate it.  That will be much easier if you write your script as `while sleep 60; do ... done`.  That way, to terminate the loop all you have to do is wait for the `sleep 60` process to show up, and send a `SIGTERM` to its PID.  `while true` loops are often notoriously hard to kill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first version, you only sleep if the test is truthy and `notify-send` is called successfully; but not if the test is falsy. In the second version, you only sleep in the branch where the test was falsy, and `notify-send` was *not* called. Meaning you'd get the same issue when the battery is low with that latter version.

You should probably have the script sleep in either case, regardless of what the test result is. Minimally, change the `&&` after `notify-send` to `;` in the first version to break the relation between the two commands. I'd go with spelling the `if`-statement out, though, something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
while true; do
  pct=$(
        upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0 |
        grep percentage |
        grep -Poe  "\d*"
      )
  if [ "$pct" -lt 5 ]; then
    notify-send "Battery below 5%"
  fi
  sleep 60
done
```

(Note that the `[[ .. ]]` conditional isn't a standard feature, and not all shells installed as `sh` in various systems support it.)